# Use this system of equations to make a vector function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to write these equations with as a vector function of $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$.

$$|x_1-a|^2=r_a^2$$

$$|x_2-b|^2=r_b^2$$

$$(x_1-x_2).(x_1-a)=0$$ (dot product)

$$(x_1-x_2).(x_2-b)=0$$ (dot product)

Let $$x_1 = (x_1,y_1)$$ and $$x_2=(x_2,y_2)$$

Write the system of equations in the form

$$F(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=0$$

where

$$r_a,r_b$$ are parameters in the equation.

I have to find the jacobian matrix and I have the jacobian matrix with values for $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4=0$ to control if my matrix is correct. I haven't managed to get it into correct form. I am not sure how I am to handle the vectors $x_1,x_2$ in the equations when I find the partial derivatives to build the jacobian matrix. Any help is appreciated but If i could have some help to find the first row of the matrix that would be very helpful. Thanks

- I am given values for vectors $a,b$ and the constants $r_b,r_b$

These are the "solution" values calculated for $r_a=1, r_b=1.5, a=(-1,1), b=(2,2.5)$

Comment: $x_1,x_2$ are vectors where their components are points on the edge of one circle each that have a radius $r_a$ and $r_b$

Comment: They have corrected it as a typo. I am sorry I didn't remember to fix it here! They also had one at $r_a=1$

Comment: Ouff. Looks fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, from the Jacobian we see that $F : \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4$.

How about:
\begin{align}
F(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) 
&=
\left(
\begin{matrix} 
(x_1 - a_1)^2 + (x_2 - a_2)^2 - r_a^2 \\
(x_3 - b_1)^2 + (x_4 - b_2)^2 - r_b^2 \\
(x_1 - x_3)(x_1 - a_1) + (x_2 - x_4)(x_2 - a_2) \\
(x_1 - x_3)(x_3 - b_1) + (x_2 - x_4)(x_4 - b_2)
\end{matrix}
\right) 
\\
&=
\left(
\begin{matrix} 
(x_1 - a_1)^2 + (x_2 - a_2)^2 - r_a^2 \\
(x_3 - b_1)^2 + (x_4 - b_2)^2 - r_b^2 \\
x_1^2 -(x_3+a_1)x_1 + a_1 x_3  + x_2^2 - (x_4 + a_2) x_2 + a_2 x_4 \\
x_1 (x_3 - b_1) - x_3^2 + b_1 x_3 + x_2 (x_4 - b_2) - x_4^2 + b_2 x_4
\end{matrix}
\right)
\end{align}
where $x_1 = (x_1, x_2)$, $x_2 = (x_3, x_4)$, $a = (a_1, a_2)$ and $b = (b_1, b_2)$.

Each of the four components $F_i$ of $F$ encode one of the four equations from above in terms of the $F$ arguments, which are the four components of the two vectors $x_1$ and $x_2$. If $F$ vanishes, it vanishes for all four $F_i$, meaning the four equations hold.

Then
$$
J = 
\left(
\frac{\partial F_i}{\partial x_j}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
2(x_1 - a_1) & 2(x_2 - a_2) & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2(x_3 - b_1) & 2(x_4 - b_2) \\
2 x_1 - x_3 - a_1 & 2 x_2 - (x_4+a_2) & -x_1+a_1 & -x_2 + a_2 \\ 
x_3-b_1 & x_4-b_2 & x_1 -2 x_3 + b_1 & x_2 - 2 x_4 + b_2
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain what $x_1,x_2,a_1,a_2$ represent?

Comment: How did you get the first equation of the vector function F. I don't understand how you got the components of the vector function

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to help me :)

Comment: Your matrix doesn't agree with the "solution" matrix. Well the last two rows. Is that what you mean with be modified later or?

Comment: :-) Appreciate your efforts and time!